# Spring Security XML can't find tag with error cvc-complex-type.2.4.c

Tags: xml, spring, security, xsd

I have a problem with Spring Security.
Eclipse can't find the html tag in the spring-security.xml with this error :

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c : 
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'
```

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
">

  <http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
  </http>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <user-service>
        <user name="user1" password="1111" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
      </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

The problem is with the first tag, html, but I can't find any issue with the xsd configuration.

Any ideas ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure it's about the `http` tag? The coordinates in the error message point to the `pattern` value in the above xml. What is the entire error message you get?

Comment: here is the entire error message : Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 28; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c : Le caractère générique concordant est strict, mais aucune déclaration ne peut être trouvée pour l'élément `'http'`. Sorry for the french! But you can see the http tag ;)

Comment: Please check that Spring jars are not missing, are you using Maven?

Comment: yes but actually, there was a problem with maven and spring security. when i put the dependencies, I have an error on a view with two errors. `The hierarchy of the type RepartitionExcelReportView is inconsistent` on the classname and `The hierarchy of the type RepartitionExcelReportView is inconsistent` on the parentclass. I couldn't find any solution so currently I include the jars directly in the buildpath.

Comment: Well, I'm back with this version because there is a problem here.. Any idea to correct these hierachy problems ?

Comment: Problem solved. it was a problem with dependencies in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing the `spring-security-config` dependency where all XSD files are found.

Be sure to declare this one if it's not in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```